# Spark: How to send arguments to Spark foreach function

Tags: redis, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to save the contents of a Spark RDD to Redis with the following code

```
import redis
class RedisStorageAdapter(BaseStorageAdapter):
    @staticmethod
    def save(record):

        ###--- How do I get action_name ---- ###
        redis_key = #<self.source_action_name>
        redis_host=settings['REDIS']['HOST']
        redis_port=settings['REDIS']['PORT']
        redis_db=settings['REDIS']['DB']

        redis_client = redis.StrictRedis(redis_host, redis_port, redis_db)
        redis_client.sadd(redis_key, record)

    def store_output(self, results_rdd):

        print self.source_action_name
        results_rdd.foreach(RedisStorageAdapter.save)
```

But I want the Redis Key to be different based on what self.source_action_name is initialized to (in BaseStorageAdapter)

How do I pass the source_action_name to RedisStorageAdapter.save function? foreach function only allows the name of the function to be executed and no parameter list

Also - if there is a better way to move data from RDD to Redis, let me know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course, foreach takes a function, not a function name. So you can pass to it a lambda function:

```
results_rdd.foreach(lambda x: RedisStorageAdapter.save(x, self.source_action_name))
```

Comment: Thanks! I had tried that but it kept giving me a pickling error. But that was due to the static method RedisStorageAdapter.save - moving 'save' function to a global function fixed both the issues.